# Detecting systems connected to a WiFi Router in android

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

My application has to connect to PC via WiFi.I need to scan and display all the PC's connected in the LAN,to which the WiFi router is connected.Is it possible to obtain all the names of the PC's connected.or rather I could get the IP of each system?

I found a code blockwhich scans for the WiFi network...But I think that is not i need...

The code block is :

```
wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++){
  sb.append(new Integer(i+1).toString() + ".");
  sb.append((wifiList.get(i)).toString());
  sb.append("\n");
}
```

Can I get an apt method for my problem?

Also my android application has to interact with the PC,via a Server program in Java,which i have successfully implemented using socket programming....Guys pls help....

Thnx in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes. Longer answer: way too much information to talk about in an SO post. I'd start [here](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/) and see if there's a way to make that do what you need.

Comment: but i cant find what i need in that resource...can you be some more specific with that link,please...thanks Brian

Comment: Not really. You'll need to do some legwork learning about networking and providing a discoverable service from your PC-hosted Java-based server and then the information in the link might be more help. What you're talking about implementing is non-trivial and will require pretty decent understanding of networking from both Android and Windows. There's no simple answer.

Comment: i can connect a particular system in my network using its IP specified earlier....but cant generalise for a network....

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Java-Beginners/12275-java-get-all-ip-addresses-in-a-lan.html